# How to go from v3 to v2 on Uniswap?

Tags: tokens, uniswap, exchanges, uniswapv3

There are tokens that offer a better exchange rate in version 2.
Uniswap used to offer a friendly way to switch between versions.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to switch between (router) versions is via the URL.

https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap?use=v2